# Is "seafood" inclusive of "seaweed"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, nouns, hypernyms, food

I told Korean friends not to label a (non-commercial) package of seaweed as "seafood", but it is from the sea and it is food, so now I'm not sure.

How common is it to refer to "seaweed" as "seafood"?

Does this vary from place to place?

Comment: It depends entirely on whose definition you use.  It's not a precisely-defined term (except perhaps in some government regulations).

Comment: It is more common to refer to seaweed as "Sea Vegetables".

Comment: @HotLicks are you aware of any seaweed-inclusive definitions?

Comment: Laver or kombu may be *sea food*, but that doesn't make them *seafood*, much as the [wild horses](https://www.nps.gov/asis/learn/nature/horses.htm) that play in the surf at Assateague National Seashore are *sea horses*, but very far from *seahorses*.

Comment: @choster but are the Assateague horses seafood? :)

Comment: @DavePhD Well, you won't find blackfish or igunaq in the seafood column of a menu, so I doubt that you'd find leberkäse there either, regardless of the forage.

Comment: Very surprised that nobody here has used the word, "[idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idiom)."  Virtually all languages have idioms---phrases whose meaning can not be completely understood (or perhaps not understood at all) just by understanding the meanings of the individual words.  You can find examples of Korean idioms with Google.

Comment: @jameslarge _Seafood_ isn't an idiom. As you say, idioms are **phrases**. Simplex words whose meanings happen not to be easily guessable from the word’s etymological constituents (transparent or not) are not generally considered idioms.

Comment: This might be in the same category as whether *fruits* are *vegetables*. Clearly, fruits are vegetable matter. But serve up some oranges and peaches as a *dish of vegetables*, and you might get some odd looks.

Comment: @Chenmunka FWIW seaweeds are algae, not plants, and hence not vegetables.

Comment: @Sparhawk Actually, most algae (*Archaeplastida*) ARE plants. They are listed as part of the *Kingdom Plantae* in biological taxonomy.

Comment: @O.M.Y. I'm actually a evolutionary biologist. Who works on algae amongst other things. :) I'd say it's arguable whether "plants" includes green algae, but they most certainly do not include red and brown algae, which are a large proportion of edible seaweed. "Algae" in general (specifically macroalgae) are a polyphyletic assemblage that's scattered across the evolutionary tree. [I just see you edited, but I'm still no 100% sure that this is what the common term "plant" includes. Anyway, the browns aren't included in that clade.]

Comment: @Sparhawk You replied just as I edited my answer to "most algae". Brown algae are definitely not plants but modern taxonomy puts red and green into the same clade under the *Plantae* branch. Of course taxonomy and classification are constantly being revised so this may not last.

Comment: @O.M.Y. Looking at my original comment, perhaps I should revise. While it's arguable whether some seaweeds are plants, *all* seaweeds are not plants. Hence, my reasoning is that saying "seaweeds" are "vegetables" is wrong, because it implies (all) seaweeds are plants.

Comment: @Sparhawk, I think we both made some generalizations. I for instance assumed *kelp* was a plant but since it is composed of brown algae that is an error on my part. Ironically *kombu* which is an Asian culinary form of kelp is considered a vegetable from a cuisine perspective. I would say this is all nuts ... but then we would need to discuss what is and is not a *nut*! :)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I wasn't able to find any dictionary which included plant-based food in the definition of "seafood."

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/seafood) (American English):

> edible marine fish and shellfish

[American Heritage](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=seafood):

> Edible fish or shellfish from the sea.

[Chambers](http://chambers.co.uk/search/?query=seafood&title=21st) (British):

> Shellfish and other edible marine fish.

Some other sources:

- The US FDA has a searchable "[seafood list](https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/fdcc/?set=seafoodlist&sort=SLSN&order=ASC&startrow=1&type=basic&search=)." I did not find any plants in the list, just glancing through it.
- The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seafood) includes plant-based food, but the [simple version](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seafood) does not.
- The University of Maine's Sea Grant "[Seafood Guide](https://www.seagrant.umaine.edu/maine-seafood-guide)" lists seaweed.

So it seems like seaweed *can* be considered seafood, but it does not seem to be common practice. I would never use the term to refer to seaweed or other plant-based food.

Comment: Seaweed is a seasoning, [according to the FDA](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=fe87bb606502589e2c75e221afeb9936&mc=true&node=se21.3.184_11120&rgn=div8).  As far as I am aware, it's fairly uncommon to refer to seasonings as food in everyday usage.

Comment: I would also note that people often have "seafood allergies," which to the best of my understanding do not include seaweed.

Comment: @dma1324 Some people would also call crumbled bacon a seasoning.

Comment: @dma1324 It may be context-dependent, but I would typically understand seasonings to be included in "food". So there may be some (regional? cultural?) variation in this usage.

Comment: @dma1324 FDA might be working as a reference for American culture, but I strongly suspect, seaweed is seen as more than seasoning in Korea.

Comment: @dma1324 - and remember that in the past (fairly certain not anymore), ketchup was classified (I think by the USDA, or some other agency) as a vegetable. So, as you indicate, it's not always (never) wise to rely on what the government calls something.

Comment: @KevinFegan what really happened was a proposed rule (concerning school lunches) printed in the Federal Register had an example discussed and it was written "could credit a condiment such as pickle relish as a vegetable".  Then news media started saying the stuff about ketchup.  https://www.washingtonpost.com/archive/politics/1982/01/07/add-the-relish-stir-up-an-embarrassment/46a9bd0b-915e-442e-8b9e-1532c99ac9db/?utm_term=.d843450c4922

Comment: @KevinFegan thanks for posting that article. You saved me some embarrassment, as I had a different, incorrect recollection of that controversy.

Answer (score 28):

A state of Connecticut [definition](https://www.cga.ct.gov/2002/tob/h/2002HB-05252-R00-HB.htm) (for the purpose of a specific law concerning the requirement of a certificate of registration for the retail sale of seafood) is:

> "Seafood" means all fresh or saltwater finfish, molluscan shellfish, crustaceans and other forms of aquatic **animal** life

[emphasis added]

which would lead us to believe that plant products are *not* included in the category 'seafood'.

Comment: Académie Française; Real Academia Española; State of Connecticut ;-)

Comment: Presumably, this is for labeling laws in the sale of these foods, correct?

Comment: @trlkly the definition in this answer only applies to a particular law in Connecticut, not the rest of the USA.  It only applies to the sentence "No person, firm, corporation, limited liability company or other legal entity shall engage in the wholesale distribution of meat or meat food products or in the retail sale of seafood without first obtaining a certificate of registration."

Comment: I think the caveat/clarification contained in the previous comment is significant enough to warrant editing the answer to include it.

Comment: @JohnY ok, I added

Answer (score 5):

For a product label, it is fine to call it seafood, although a bit strange. We typically use the word seafood as a general category of foods or restaurants. Although basil is a type of plant, we wouldn't call it a vegetable.

Comment: Basil is an herb, not a vegetable. Plant-based foods are broken into a number of different categories other than vegetable. The most obvious one is of course fruit, but then there are also herbs, spices, nuts, and grains. None of these terms are interchangeable. Seeds are another category but they sometimes fall under some of the other categories, most commonly spices or grains.

Comment: @O.M.Y. the word "vegetable" has multiple definitions. The broadest one would include basil – think of the "animal, vegetable, mineral" categories in twenty questions. [AHD 1c](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=vegetable). "A member of the vegetable kingdom, especially a green plant."

Comment: @sumelic The "vegetable kingdom" (*Regnum Vegetabile*) is an archaic term from the 18th century. Today we refer to this as the "plant kingdom" (*Kingdom Plantae*) instead because it includes vegetables, fruits, non-food plants such as timber trees, and even algae. Since this StackExchange is about the English language this is not a trivial point here.

Answer (score 3):

> but it is from the sea and it is food, so now I'm not sure

This is a common misconception. Language categories don't work at all like mathematical sets, but most of us are unaware of it. So people try to treat them as they were working that way, or even start insisting that language is "incorrect" because it doesn't obey the same rules.

In mathematics, sets are defined by their inclusion conditions. If a triangle has two equal sides, it belongs to the set of isosceles triangles, else it doesn't.

In language, category membership is defined by the degree of similarity to a prototypical item, and it is gradual, unlike set membership. The prototypical "bread" in American English is a tin-baked spongy loaf leavened with yeast. A Central European style sourdough boule loaf is still quite universally recognized as "bread" even though it is not the first one that comes to mind to an American. Items like challah or a banana bread are farther apart and some people under some circumstances will say "yes" when asked if they are bread, while other people in other contexts will say "no". But if you ask an American baker if a Liege waffle is bread, I expect the answer to be a resounding "no". At the same time, if you ask American bakers what makes a bread bread, the first criterion that comes to mind will probably be "it is a baked good made with yeast" (and a Liege waffle is made with yeast). So, while the criteria do exist, you cannot apply them the same way as you can apply them to sets. ("If it is baked and made with yeast, it is bread").

So of course you can ask for a definition of a category, but have to be aware that not all items which fit the definition are actual members of the category, and that items which don't fit the definition can act as a member of the category (permanently or under special circumstances).

This explains your confusion. You assumed that "if it is food, and comes from the sea, it must be seafood". Unlike a geometrical figure ("if it is a triangle, and has a right angle, it must be a right triangle") seafood does not care for a boolean match of necessary and sufficient conditions. You have to look at the traditional usage and the prototype items of the category.

This is what your brain did naturally the first time, before you started second-guessing your wisdom. Edible seaweed is certainly not considered seafood by native English speakers, at least within the US and British cultures. I don't know the exact prototype item for the category, but my guess would be that it is some subset (mathematically defined this time) of mussels, scallops, shrimps and fish.

If you are interesting in background reading on membership in linguistic categories, I can highly recommend George Lakoff.

Answer (score 0):

I asked my wife who works in the industry, selling food and supplies to restaurants.

*seafood* is indeed inclusive of vegetables, specifically sea weed.

Answer (score 0):

Seafood generally applies to crustaceans, fish, cephalopods, and ocean mammals; basically sea animals. Here's a definition from Merriam-Webster that says that: edible marine fish and shellfish. Seaweed would be considered food from the sea, but not necessarily seafood. Seaweeds are plants and algae, so not animals. Marking it as seafood would likely confuse English speakers.

Answer (score -2):

I think this belongs in a different category, given the "classical" definition of seafood belonging to fish, shellfish, etc.  May I propose "seagan" or "seagetarian"?

Now, if this is purely a "practical" definition we're seeking here that will get you past customs, go with "vegetable" or "plant material".  Warning, though, it might not make it through some Customs inspections due to limitations on what can be transported across borders, regardless of whether you pick a "P.C." name or not.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please note that this is not a discussion forum, but a Q&A site; you can suggest neologistic alternatives, but you must make an effort to answer the original question, including appropriate references, links, and examples demonstrating actual usage. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for a better understanding of the goals of our site and the ways to contribute.